# How to bind a dynamic class to an element in Handlebars and Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

So I'm currently building a chat application and I need to bind a dynamic class to messages to define whether it is the senders message or the recipient. However, I'm not sure how to bind this class to an element with my current code:

*Messages template*

```
<ul class="content conversation" id="conversation">
    {{#each message in messages}}
        <li>
            {{messageHighlight currentUser.id message.sender_id}}
            <div class="avatar">
                <img {{bind-attr   src="message.thumb"}} />
            </div>
            <div class="chat-message">
                <p>{{message.text}}</p>
                    <time>
                    {{message.sender.username}} • {{message.created_at}}
                    </time>
                </div>  
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

*Highlight helper*

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('messageHighlight', function(currentUserId, senderId)
{
    return (senderId == currentUserId) ? 'self' : 'other'
});
```

I tried to define my class like the following, but Handlebars threw an error:

```
<li class="{{messageHighlight currentUser.id message.sender_id}}">
```

So my question is, **how do I bind a dynamic class to an attribute while passing in parameters?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the error when you tried `<li class="{{messageHighlight currentUser.id message.sender_id}}">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the error message was the following: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: An error occured while setting up template bindings. Please check for invalid markup or bindings within HTML comments.`

Comment: Check out the jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jogufa/2/edit

Comment: Also what version of ember are you using. You need to be using Ember 1.11.0 or greater to use bound attributes with out using `bind-attr`

Comment: @kiwiupover just tried the what was contained in the example and it provides the same error, I even tried `<li class='{{messageHighlight 1 1}}'>`. I'm using Ember 1.9.1...that might be why...

Comment: That is why  you need to update to Ember 1.11.0.

Comment: Otherwise you will need to make a computed property in a component and  use the component for the contents of your `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an escaped string from the helper.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('messageHighlight', function(currentUserId, senderId) {
  var klass =  (senderId == currentUserId) ? 'self' : 'other';
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(klass);
});
```

In the template

```
<li class="{{messageHighlight currentUser.id message.sender_id}}" >The message</li>
```

Here is a working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jogufa/2/edit)

FYI you need to be using Ember 1.11.0 or great to use bound attributes with out using `{{bind-attr}}`

Using Ember 1.10 or below you could use a component for the contents of the `li` like this.

```
<ul class="content conversation" id="conversation">
    {{#each message in messages}}
        {{chat-message message=message currentUser=currentUser}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

chat-message.js component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: [messageHighlight],

  messageHighlight(){
    return (message.sender.id == currentUser.Id) ? 'self' : 'other'
  }
});
```

chat-message.hbs template:

```
  <div class="avatar">
    <img {{bind-attr src="message.thumb"}} />
  </div>
  <div class="chat-message">
    <p>{{message.text}}</p>
    <time>
      {{message.sender.username}} • {{message.created_at}}
    </time>
 </div>
```

Comment: Updated comments about Ember v1.11.0 supporting new 'Bound attrbiute syntax' functionality, see the following for more info: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html